# How to import data as a date/time in to SQL

Tags: sql-server, runtime-error

I try to import date/time from Excel with VBA into SQL:

Here is my code :

```
 Order = CDbl(row.Cells(1).Value)
    PlanProductionTime = CDbl(row.Cells(2).Value)
    Cavity = CDbl(row.Cells(3).Value)
    Toynum = row.Cells(4).Value
    STD = CDbl(row.Cells(5).Value)
    DT = row.Cells(6).Value 'it's date/time data from exel
            
    Sql = "insert into STDCT values(" & Order & "," & PlanProductionTime & "," & Cavity & ",'" & Toynum & "'," & STD & ",'" & DT & "')"
    Sql2 = "delete STDCT where [Order] = '0'"
    
    con.Execute Sql
    con.Execute Sql2
```

Comment: run time error - conversion failed when converting data and/or time from character string.

Comment: I expect that `DT` is actually an Excel date serial number - have you printed it out somewhere? To be DATEFORMAT-agnostic in SQL Server you should format it `'yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss'`.

Comment: codeing on exel to get date/time on row.cell(6) : =IF([@Order]="","",IF(F2="",NOW(),F2))

Comment: i already done it , i forgot to change my scope of my data xD